# No matching action was found on controller logging

Tags: asp.net, .net

We are occasionally getting this exception on our production servers. Unfortunately we are not able to reproduce the error. We have any unhanded exceptions written to a log file.

Is there any way that we can see what action the request was trying to target?

UPDATE: Added Exception catch Code

```
protected override void OnError()
{
    base.OnError();

    var error = Server.GetLastError();

    OutboundEmailQueueItem.EmailException(error);
}
```

Comment: post your code. Nobody can't help until will see your code, where an error occurs

Comment: so it is happening across random elements of the application. It could well be just a bot trying random URL's which at times happen to match a controller name, but we need to log this to confirm. have added code where we catch the exception

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that we can see what action the request was trying to target?

You can try to log request paths got from [HttpRequest.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is available from [current context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That seems better as to my mind requests can be to anything. After that you can filter those by controllers and get what actions are missing.

Comment: sorry for delay. This managed to solve issue, problem was actually that some functions were calling a POST action via GET